# Possible to add some sort of identification onto list items?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, list

I'm just curious if it's possible to gather a list of data and put it into a list or array and easily pull them out using some variable(like a tag property on controls) on each item in the list rather than using the index.  An example would be if i have many controls on a form and would like to populate the values using the list but instead of having to cross check a lot of different indicies(would take a lot of time) i could just assign the label to some 'tag like' variable for the list item.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists in .NET, such as the `List(Of T)` class, only support storing one object per item.  However, the beauty of them is, you can store any type of object that you want.  If you need to store metadata with your data, simply create a new class that holds all the data for each item.  For instance:

```
Public Class MyControlData
    Public Property LabelText As String
    Public Property Value As String
End Class
```

Then you can add the items to the list like this:

```
Dim dataList As New List(Of MyControlData)()
Dim item As New MyControlData()
item.LabelText = "Name"
item.Value = "Bob"
dataList.Add(item)
```

And you can read the data from the list like this:

```
For Each i As MyControlData in dataList
    Label1.Text = i.LabelText
    TextBox1.Text = i.Value
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) object so you can use a key to reference your data easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ:

```
Dim myTagControls = From ctrl In Me.Controls.Cast(Of Control)()
                    Where "your-tag".Equals(ctrl.Tag)

For Each ctrl In myTagControls
    Console.WriteLine("Tag:{0} Name:{1}", ctrl.Tag, ctrl.Name)
Next
```